# How to delete all records of a table in MS Access using VB6 ADO

Tags: ms-access, vb6

I want to delete all records of a table in MS Access using VB.6 code.

Actually I'm going to reset my database with it, by that I mean to have NO records anymore.

How can I do that?

Comment: Do you mean delete all records in all tables? If so, I have code that will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & App.Path &    "\DB.mdb"
cnn.Open
cnn.Execute "delete * from LogTBL"
cnn.Close
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that will delete all records in all tables of the Access database you are connected to. HOWEVER!! If you have built relationships between tables and have not specified 'Cascade Delete', then you can't delete the 'owner' table until deleting from the 'member' table.  One way around that is to add an error trap so that you check that condition, then ignore (Resume Next). But then you would need to repeat running this code until no errors. You need to set your connection string (see comment in code)!!

```
Function Delete_All_Data()
Dim cnLocalData     As ADODB.Connection
Dim catLocal        As ADOX.Catalog
Dim tdf             As ADOX.Table
Dim strSQL          As String
Dim strTableName    As String

    Set cnLocalData = New ADODB.Connection

    MsgBox " Add code to connect to your database either using Connection cnLocalData or your own and change this code!!!"

    Set catLocal = New ADOX.Catalog
    catLocal.ActiveConnection = cnLocalData

    For Each tdf In catLocal.Tables
        If UCase(tdf.Type) = "TABLE" And UCase(Left(tdf.Name, 4)) <> "MSYS" Then
            if tdf.Name <> "INFOTBL" Then
                strTableName = tdf.Name
                strSQL = "delete * from [" & strTableName & "];"
                cnLocalData.Execute strSQL
            End If
        End If
    Next tdf
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set catLocal = Nothing
    cnLocalData.Close
    Set cnLocalData = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Hi thanks
It has Errors,
Ho can I Do it as easily?
I have Some Table,I want delete all records of its Except INFOTBL .

Comment: 1. Which line gave you the error; 2. What error code and message and what values used? 3. Did you establish the proper connection to your Access database?

Comment: 1.in ADOX.Catalog and ADOX.Table
2.user defined
3.Yes

Never mind I found My Answer,you can see in next post,Bye

Comment: The reason for those errors is you need to add a Reference to your project for 'Microsoft ADO Ext. n.n for DDL and Security' (where n.n is the highest version number)